# Why does stringForKey return null?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

in my **viewDidLoad** method I want to read the user defaults. But

```
NSLog(@"%@", [prefs stringForKey:@"gateway_picker"]);
```

prints `(null)`. Why?

`gateway_picker` default value is set to **1**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is set to the number 1, as either an integer, a float, or a Boolean, and unlike an NSControl, NSUserDefaults does not attempt to convert the value to the type you requested.

Use `objectForKey:` instead. This will return the object regardless of whether it is a string or anything else.

If you then want to interpret it numerically, ask the object for its `integerValue`, `floatValue`, or `boolValue`. This will work regardless of whether the object is an NSString or any kind of NSNumber. (If it is a data, date, array, or dictionary, this will cause an exception. You may want to detect such values and substitute the default value in that case.)

If you specifically want a string, detect whether the object is a number and ask it for its `stringValue` if it is. (Again, you may want to also handle receiving a data, date, array, or dictionary.)